# How to parse a string "instruction and comma separated arguments" to appropriate instruction implementing class in Java?

Tags: java, csv, data-binding, pojo

I have a file with Instructions `instructionName comma,separated,arguments`

```
instructionA argumentA1,argumentA2,argumentA3,...,argumentAn-a
instructionB argumentB1,argumentB2,argumentB3,...,argumentBn-b
.
.
.
```

and I have an interface

```java
/**
 * executes instruction and returns Status
 *    which is Enum which tells if execution succeeded or failed for some reason;
 */
public interface Instruction {
    Status execute();
}
```

and class for each instruction

```java
// with setters, no arg & all arg constructors
public class InstructionA implements Instruction {
    TypeA1 argumentA1;
    TypeA2 argumentA2;
    .
    .
    .
    TypeAn-a argumentAn-a;

    @overrides
    public Status execute() {
        // execute and return status;
    }
}
```

I want to parse the instructions file and get list of instructions

```java
    public void readAndExecuteAll(String fileName) {
        List<Instruction> instructions = parseInstructionsFromFile(fileName);
        for (Instruction instruction : instructions) {
            Status status = instruction.execute();
            // log or do-something with status
        }
    }
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? What did you try so far? Reading the file line by line and splitting each line into instruction name and arguments shouldn't be too hard. Then feed the instruction name and argument list to some factory that constructs the correct instance.

Comment: I tired implementing a factory which maps instructionName to ImplementingClass, stringOfCSVArgumentNames, openCsvParserObjectForClass. The problem is, for each instruction I add, I'll manually need to update factory map with new class, arguments, create new object etc. Currently i'm looking into implementing annotations and am trying to do it from there, but am looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Read file content and split by comma delimeter

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(FilePath), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
String.join("", lines);
String[] csl = lines.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single factory that creates instruction instances you could use a factory repository, e.g.:

```
interface InstructionFactory {
  String getInstructionName();

  Instruction createInstruction(Collection<String> arugments);
}
```

Then you maintain a repository of factories, e.g.:

```
 class InstructionRepo {
    Map<String, InstructionFactory> factories;

    Instruction createInstruction(String instructionName, Collection<String> arguments) {
      return factories.get(instructionName).createInstruction(arguments);
    }
 }
```

In your instruction implementations you'd maintain a corresponding factory:

```
class InstructionA implements Instruction {
  public static class Factory implements InstructionFactory {
    public String getInstructionName() {
       return "instructionA";
    }

    public Instruction createInstruction(Collection<String> arugments) {
      //create instance of InstructionA and return it
    }
  }
}
```

Then use something like SPI or CDI/Spring bean discovery to pick up the factories and register them with your repo. Note that it might be necessary to pull the factories to their own files instead of having static nested classes.